# Why does the minimum value of $x^x$ equal $1/e$?

Tags: calculus, exponential-function, exponentiation

The graph of $y=x^x$ looks like this:

[image: Graph of y=x^x.]

As we can see, the graph has a minimum value at a turning point. According to WolframAlpha, this point is at $x=1/e$.

I know that $e$ is the number for exponential growth and $\frac{d}{dx}e^x=e^x$, but these ideas seem unrelated to the fact that the mimum value of $x^x$ is $1/e$. **Is this just pure coincidence, or could someone provide an intuitive explanation** (i.e. more than just a proof) **of why this is?**

Comment: I would appeal to the logarithmic derivative of the function to show that.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Hint: Note that $x^x = e^{x\log x}$.

So minimizing $x^x$ is the same as minimizing $x\log x$

Comment: But why is e special here? Doesn't this work for any log base, i.e., x^x = b^(x log{b} x)?

Comment: That would be the natural log, not the common log

Answer (score 7):

Let $f(x)=x^x$. Note that $f(x)$ is only defined for $x>0$.

Then
$$
\ln f(x)=x\cdot\ln x\tag{1}
$$
Differentiating (1) gives
$$
\frac{1}{f(x)}f^\prime(x)=x\frac{1}{x}+\ln x=1+\ln x
$$
Note that we have used the chain rule and the product rule.

Solving for $f^\prime(x)$ gives
$$
f^\prime(x)=f(x)(1+\ln x)=x^x(1+\ln x)
$$
Can you use this to locate the critical points of $f(x)$?

Comment: I think you can leave the absolute value off since $x>0$ on its domain, right?

Comment: @Subjunctive sure

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: actually you are looking for a local/global minimum .. so look at the derivative of the function $f(x) = x^x$
$$f'(x) = x^x (\log (x)+1)$$
which equals $0 \iff x = \frac{1}{e}$

Answer (score 2):

Try to minimize logarithm of  $ y= x^x,$ i.e., $y=x \, \log x$

Its derivative is

$$ 1 + \log(x) $$

When equated to zero, it solves to that the minimum of $y(x)$ ocuurs at

$$ x= \dfrac{1}{e}= 0.36788$$

and the minimum value is

$$ y_{min}= \dfrac{1}{{e}^{\frac{1}{e}}} \approx 0.6922$$

The tiny red dot shown in your graph for minimum is:

$$ (x,y) = (0.36788, 0.6922) $$

Note that the minimum value is not $\dfrac{1}{e}\, ! \, $ ... but is the reciprocal of $e^{th} $root of $e.$